# DefaultJmsHeaderMapper - failed to map Message header 'timestamp' to JMS property

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a problem with the '`timestamp`' header that comes from the [JMSMessageProperties](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-2239/6ndrt6vgu/index.html) class, or so it seems to me, and it causes the following error

```
[WARN ] [2022-04-06 14:49:03,758] [voryouDuplicateCheck.container-1] DefaultJmsHeaderMapper - failed to map Message header 'timestamp' to JMS property
javax.jms.MessageNotWriteableException: Message properties are read-only
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.checkReadOnlyProperties(ActiveMQMessage.java:740) ~[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.setObjectProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:494) ~[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.setObjectProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:488) ~[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.fromHeaders(DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.java:152) [spring-integration-jms-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.fromHeaders(DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.java:57) [spring-integration-jms-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler$HeaderMappingMessagePostProcessor.postProcessMessage(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:167) [spring-integration-jms-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$7.createMessage(JmsTemplate.java:686) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:593) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:562) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:682) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.send(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:143) [spring-integration-jms-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:116) [spring-integration-jms-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:168) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150) [spring-messaging-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42) [spring-messaging-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:459) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:426) [spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.sendAndReceiveMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:512) [spring-integration-jms-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:344) [spring-integration-jms-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) [spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

I know this is due to the `checkReadOnly` variable in `ActiveMQMessage` class and the following methods are responsible for this

```
  @Override
    public void setObjectProperty(String name, Object value) throws JMSException {
        setObjectProperty(name, value, true);
    }

    public void setObjectProperty(String name, Object value, boolean checkReadOnly) throws JMSException {

        if (checkReadOnly) {
            checkReadOnlyProperties();
        }
        if (name == null || name.equals("")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Property name cannot be empty or null");
        }

        if (value instanceof UTF8Buffer) {
            value = value.toString();
        }

        checkValidObject(value);
        value = convertScheduled(name, value);
        PropertySetter setter = JMS_PROPERTY_SETERS.get(name);

        if (setter != null && value != null) {
            setter.set(this, value);
        } else {
            try {
                this.setProperty(name, value);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw JMSExceptionSupport.create(e);
            }
        }
    }

  private void checkReadOnlyProperties() throws MessageNotWriteableException {
        if (readOnlyProperties) {
            throw new MessageNotWriteableException("Message properties are read-only");
        }
    }
```

and the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` class ich catching the `Exception` and logging this as WARN

```
@Override
public void fromHeaders(MessageHeaders headers, javax.jms.Message jmsMessage) {
    try {
        Object jmsCorrelationId = headers.get(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID);
        if (jmsCorrelationId instanceof Number) {
            jmsCorrelationId = jmsCorrelationId.toString();
        }
        if (jmsCorrelationId instanceof String) {
            try {
                jmsMessage.setJMSCorrelationID((String) jmsCorrelationId);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                this.logger.info("failed to set JMSCorrelationID, skipping", e);
            }
        }
        Object jmsReplyTo = headers.get(JmsHeaders.REPLY_TO);
        if (jmsReplyTo instanceof Destination) {
            try {
                jmsMessage.setJMSReplyTo((Destination) jmsReplyTo);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                this.logger.info("failed to set JMSReplyTo, skipping", e);
            }
        }
        Object jmsType = headers.get(JmsHeaders.TYPE);
        if (jmsType instanceof String) {
            try {
                jmsMessage.setJMSType((String) jmsType);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                this.logger.info("failed to set JMSType, skipping", e);
            }
        }
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            String headerName = entry.getKey();
            if (StringUtils.hasText(headerName) && !headerName.startsWith(JmsHeaders.PREFIX)
                    && jmsMessage.getObjectProperty(headerName) == null) {
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                if (value != null) {
                    if (SUPPORTED_PROPERTY_TYPES.contains(value.getClass())) {
                        try {
                            String propertyName = this.fromHeaderName(headerName);
                            jmsMessage.setObjectProperty(propertyName, value);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            if (headerName.startsWith("JMSX")
                                    || headerName.equals(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.PRIORITY)) {
                                if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                                    this.logger.trace("skipping reserved header, it cannot be set by client: "
                                            + headerName);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (this.logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                                this.logger.warn("failed to map Message header '" + headerName + "' to JMS property", e); // **<-- this part**
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID.equals(headerName)) {
                        String propertyName = fromHeaderName(headerName);
                        jmsMessage.setObjectProperty(propertyName, value.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (this.logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            this.logger.warn("error occurred while mapping from MessageHeaders to JMS properties", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is just a warning but we want to keep logs clean so the idea is to not log this specific WARN or try to not pass the `header`.
I've create a custom mapper based on `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` and use it but as u can see in the starcktrace the default one is still in use.

Here the configuration in XML file

```
<bean id="voryouDuplicateCheckQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
      <constructor-arg index="0" value="voryouDuplicateCheck${jms.queue.postfix}" />
      </bean>
   
   <bean id="voryouDuplicateCheckCustomJmsHeaderMapper" class="com.example.ws.impl.voryou.CustomJmsHeaderMapper" >
   </bean>
    <int-jms:inbound-gateway id="voryouDuplicateCheck"
                      request-destination="voryouDuplicateCheckQueue"
                      request-channel="voryouDuplicateCheckChannel"
                      extract-request-payload="false" 
                      header-mapper="voryouDuplicateCheckCustomJmsHeaderMapper"
                      auto-startup="true"
                     
                       />
                      
   <int:channel id="voryouDuplicateCheckChannel">
      <int:interceptors>      
         <int:wire-tap channel="loggingServiceChannel" />
      </int:interceptors>
   </int:channel>
                      
   <int:service-activator id="activatorSasoVoryouDuplicateCheck" input-channel="voryouDuplicateCheckChannel" ref="voryouDuplicateCheckBES"
      method="getRequest" output-channel="loggingChannel" />
```

Have any of you encountered a similar problem and found any solution?
The main goal is not to log this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 4.3.x is no longer supported. The last 4.3.x. version was 4.3.24  at the end of 2020.

Second, it is strange that the properties are marked as read-only during message creation.

One way to avoid the log is to set the log level for the header mapper to ERROR.

Comment: Your stacktrace points to the `JmsSendingMessageHandler`, but you show configuration for the `<int-jms:inbound-gateway>` . See if you can use your custom header mapper in the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

Comment: You were right @ArtemBilan, there was a custom global `outbound-channel` for logging purposes and he was guilty of the whole mess.
Thank You!